# How to get current media status from 3rd party MediaPlayer activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm launching a new activity, which launches default android movie player application to play specified url.

Now I was wondering if it's possible for me to universally get current timestamp of the video, so that I can resume it next time.

I can implement my own mediaplayer, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it via 3rd party media player, as most people want to watch videos in their preferred movie player.

I already tried overriding onActivityResult, but 3rd party applications don't return any data. I tested all of this using [MXPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad).

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    println("Request code: $requestCode")
    println("Result code: $resultCode")
    if(data != null) {
        println("Data: " + data.extras)
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

returns this

```
Request code: 1337
Result code: 0
```

I'd like to have current timestamp of the video returned, so that I'd be able to continue the playback where they left off.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that. If you need that, I suggest you just use the MediaPlayer android class to display the video.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I guess I really should do that then